# Send-only SMTP mail via postfix rejected by relayhost (550-Please turn on SMTP Authentication)

Tags: postfix, smtp

I want to configure a Centos 8 machine to send emails via an external SMTP relay.  (I control the Centos box and have no control over the external relay).

I've read countless posts on how to set up `postfix` to do this but mail sent via:

```
echo "Test Mail" | mailx -r centUser@company1.com -s "from centUser" someUser@domain.com
```

is rejected by the relay host with: `550-Please turn on SMTP Authentication in your mail client`

I've configured `/etc/postfix/sasl_passwd` and created the hash file with `postmap /etc/postfix/sasl_passwd`

Any suggestions?  I've tried everything in the posts but no progress.

**postconf -n output**

```
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
command_directory = /usr/sbin
compatibility_level = 2
daemon_directory = /usr/libexec/postfix
data_directory = /var/lib/postfix
debug_peer_level = 10
debugger_command = PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin ddd $daemon_directory/$process_name $process_id & sleep 5
html_directory = no
inet_interfaces = localhost
inet_protocols = all
mail_owner = postfix
mailq_path = /usr/bin/mailq.postfix
manpage_directory = /usr/share/man
meta_directory = /etc/postfix
mydestination = $myhostname, localhost.$mydomain, localhost
newaliases_path = /usr/bin/newaliases.postfix
queue_directory = /var/spool/postfix
readme_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix/README_FILES
relayhost = [mail.relayHost.com]:465
sample_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix/samples
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail.postfix
setgid_group = postdrop
shlib_directory = /usr/lib64/postfix
smtp_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtp_sasl_password_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sasl_passwd
smtp_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtp_tls_CAfile = /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
smtp_tls_CApath = /etc/pki/tls/certs
smtp_tls_security_level = encrypt
smtp_tls_wrappermode = yes
smtp_use_tls = yes
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/pki/tls/certs/postfix.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/pki/tls/private/postfix.key
smtpd_tls_security_level = may
unknown_local_recipient_reject_code = 550
```

**/var/log/maillog contents :**

```
Mar 10 19:03:59 localhost postfix/pickup[51935]: C9C78A0ECC: uid=0 from=<centUser@company1.com>
Mar 10 19:03:59 localhost postfix/cleanup[51953]: C9C78A0ECC: message-id=<6229db1f.6kZlW9/tSI+EKENo%centUser@company1.com>
Mar 10 19:03:59 localhost postfix/qmgr[51936]: C9C78A0ECC: from=<centUser@company1.com>, size=430, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Mar 10 19:04:04 localhost postfix/smtp[51955]: C9C78A0ECC: to=<someuser@domain.com>, relay=mail.relayHost.com[xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx]:465, delay=4.9, delays=0.09/0.04/1.6/3.2, dsn=5.0.0, status=bounced (host mail.relayHost.com[xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] said: 550-Please turn on SMTP Authentication in your mail client, or login to the 550-IMAP/POP3 server before sending your message.  550-bc9deedb.xxx.ispdomain.com (centUser.localdomain) [yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy]:42686 550 is not permitted to relay through this server without authentication. (in reply to RCPT TO command))
Mar 10 19:04:04 localhost postfix/cleanup[51953]: D9BC8A0ECD: message-id=<20220310110404.D9BC8A0ECD@centUser.localdomain>
Mar 10 19:04:04 localhost postfix/qmgr[51936]: D9BC8A0ECD: from=<>, size=2982, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Mar 10 19:04:04 localhost postfix/bounce[51958]: C9C78A0ECC: sender non-delivery notification: D9BC8A0ECD
Mar 10 19:04:04 localhost postfix/qmgr[51936]: C9C78A0ECC: removed
Mar 10 19:04:06 localhost postfix/smtp[51955]: D9BC8A0ECD: to=<centUser@company1.com>, relay=mail.relayHost.com[xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx]:465, delay=1.6, delays=0.04/0/1.1/0.48, dsn=5.0.0, status=bounced (host mail.relayHost.com[xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] said: 550-Please turn on SMTP Authentication in your mail client, or login to the 550-IMAP/POP3 server before sending your message.  550-bc9deedb.xxx.ispdomain.com (centUser.localdomain) [yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy]:42688 550 is not permitted to relay through this server without authentication. (in reply to RCPT TO command))
Mar 10 19:04:06 localhost postfix/qmgr[51936]: D9BC8A0ECD: removed
```

Answer (score 1):

> relayhost = [mail.relayHost.com]:465

Your relayhost uses port 465 which is Submission over TLS, you definitely need authentication and TLS to be allowed to relay your e-mail through this server.

See the section *Enabling SASL authentication in the Postfix SMTP/LMTP client* in the official documentation which is [available here](http://www.postfix.org/SASL_README.html#client_sasl)